# java compiler method resolution

Tags: java, compiler-errors, dependencies

i have a problem to understand why the java compiler sees a private method that he shouldn't see when compiling a class. i found this error in my project when i added some dependency exclusions. may be somebody can explain whats going on here.

so the maven project structure is:

```
root
  |-a
  |-b
  +-c

dependencies are this:
- a depends on b and excludes c
- b depends on c
```

given these classes:

**module: c**

```
package test;

public class Dto {
    private String value;

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

**module: b**

```
package test;

public class Service {
    public void execute(String val1, String val2) {
        Dto dto = new Dto();
        dto.setValue(val1);
        execute(dto, val2);
    }

    private void execute(Dto val1, String val2) {
        System.out.println("val1 = [" + val1 + "], val2 = [" + val2 + "]");
    }
}
```

**module: a**

```
package test;

public class Runner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.execute("Hello", "World");
    }
}
```

so what now happens is module **c** and **b** are compiling successfully but module **a** fails with the following message

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project a: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Users/user/IdeaProjects/test/a/src/main/java/test/Runner.java:[6,16] cannot access test.Dto
[ERROR] class file for test.Dto not found
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
```

when i change the name of the private method everything is fine and all modules compile successfully

so the question is why does the compiler see or try to use the private method when compiling module **a**

Comment: it seems to a bug of the compiler for the overloaded methods. you may need to provide the jdk version in here.

Comment: You said "`a` depends on `b` and excludes `c`" but `test.Dto` class is in `c`. So how `a` is supposed to find that class?

Comment: I'm sure it is a jdk bug, it is failed even if you compile the module `a` with the standlone compiled `b.jar`. the compiler will resolving the unrelated private overloaded method.

Comment: I tested with jdk8 152 and JDK9 9.0.3. Exclution was only done for finding a dependency issues not related to the actual simple reproducer. It happens also when compiling on command line.

Comment: 1. You are using quite an older version of maven-compiler-plugin.(specifically trying to build with java-9) 2. You need to make sure if you need classes from module c into module a then you shouldn't exclude it. Your maven pom.xml of the three modules would clear this picture. 3. Let's put the tags for Java version if you find the code specifically not working for either of those. 4. Irrespective of the public or private method being executed, the `Dto` class would certainly be required for your `Runner`, so its tough to believe that renaming just the private method solves this compile error.

Comment: Managed to reproduce also, `maven-compiler-plugin` versions 3.1.0 & 3.7.0. Exclusion with original method name causes compilation failure `cannot access test.Dto class file for test.Dto not found` renaming method allows compiling, running causes then `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`. Using `OpenJDK 1.8.0_151`

Comment: I know it will not run, this is not the question, the question is why does the compiler see this private method and takes into consideration when compiling the class. Also it is not maven related the same happens when just using javac command line tool when not specifieng module c.jar in classpath when compiling a

Comment: @BigMichi1 If you meant my comment: my comment was a "partial reply" to a comment from nullpointer, not an answer to your question :) It was just confirmation that the problem exists in my env also and it did some exclusions about the possible assumptions in points 1) & 4). And yes: it is not Maven related. Maven just uses `javac` by default.